# retrieving php arrays containing whitespace with jQuery.parseJSON

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

Everything is working fine when I retrieve integers or strings with no white space. but when I retrieve fields such as description which contain white space and other characters the javascript stops from functioning.

my javascript (which is in the same file as my php):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var x = new Array();
x = jQuery.parseJSON('<?php echo json_encode($tt) ?>');

$("#ty").html(x[0]["dnp"]);
});
```

my php:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM D") or die (mysql_error());

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($sql);

if ($num_rows > 0)
{   
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$dd = $row['Description'];
if (!(isset($tt)) || (count($tt)<1))
{    
$tt = array(0 => array("dnp" => $dd));
}
else
{
array_push($tt , array("dnp" => $dd));
}
}
}
```

what am I missing?

Comment: we need an example json string that failed

Comment: Take a 100% healthy!! lunch today.

this description failed

Comment: Please provide the full json string, not only the value of it. Also are you getting a JS error message?

Comment: what json string? This value is fetched from the database (field: "Description" VARCHAR(1000)). If i feed the array the value string as is, everything works fine, but if I fetch it directly from the database(as in my code above), put in the array and fetch it by Jquery then the javascript stops functioning (I don't get an error, it stops working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

json is javascript. You don't need to supply it as a string and then parse it.

```
x = <?php echo json_encode($tt) ?>;
```

This should do.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you,

```
//var x = new Array();         
x = jQuery.parseJSON('<?php echo json_encode($tt) ?>');
$("#ty").html(x.dnp);
```